# Issue while Executing the chromeDriver in Heroku - Java Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, heroku, bitbucket

I am unable to exceute the ChromeDriver in heroku ,tried below methods but no luck

Placed linux chromedriver and set the path in source code as below

```
String UserPath =System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",UserPath+"/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```

Note : UserPath takes the generated path value

2)Applied the buildpack in heroku

- heroku/java
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java

3)Even tried setting up the binary path as below
First Method ->

```
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome");
```

second method ->

```
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable");
```

Error Message while trying to push to heroku

```
Working Directory = /tmp/build_790de6ef0cc5cb6adc2f673a25a9d247 [WARNING] java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

Note:The Path "/app/.apt/opt/google/chrome/chrome" is based on path specified for chromedriver in system.setproperty()

Please assist me on this issue.

Comment: You should use chromedriver.exe.

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",UserPath+"/chromedriver.exe");

Comment: What is the exact issue you see when you say `unable to exceute`?

Answer (score 0):

this is the config that works for me.

It's Java 8, Maven and Springboot.

```
System.setProperty("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN", "/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome"); 
System.setProperty("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH", "/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome");   
options.addArguments("--enable-javascript"); 
options.addArguments("--headless"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); 
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://the-web_you_want");
```