# Failing using chromedriver when it is on Heroku

Tags: java, selenium, github, heroku, selenium-chromedriver

I have discord bot which is meant to return leaderboard data from one website. This code works perfectly on my macbook, but when I upload this code to Heroku, it returns this error:

```
/app/chromedriver: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
app[worker.1]: [JDA MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception
app[worker.1]: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

My code for this command:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
options.addArguments("--lang=en");
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--headless");
//options.setBinary("chromedriver") - doesn't work for me.
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("https://hordes.io/players");

driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr")).get(0).findElements(By.tagName("th")).get(n).click();

try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}

List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

When I tried to use `options.setBinary("chromedriver")` it didn't work on my pc (neither for server).  I have also tried reinstalling chromedriver - didn't help. Actually it runs even without specifying chromedriver's path

What about architecture of my project, it is simple:

Project structure

[image]

Inside of src/main/java

[image]

TopPlayers is the class which uses selenium for scraping.

Chromedriver's version is 107 (as my chrome).

As the error says the problem is more likely with starting up my webDriver. I don't see many questions on this topic for java, mostly python, so I am very lost.

Comment: It looks like you're using a Chromedriver that's not compatible with the version of Linux Heroku is using. The Chromedriver is not part of your application and should not be committed in the first place. Use appropriate buildpacks instead. There are [lots of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heroku+selenium-chromedriver) about using Chromedriver on Heroku.

Comment: How do I use a buildpack? Sorry, I am new in using this and don't understand. I should put chromedriver in certain folder?

Comment: No, you shouldn't have a Chromedriver in your project at all. You need to use a buildpack, e.g. [this one](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver).

Comment: Every guidance I find is about adding buildpacks via command lines. But I used github to deploy my project and I can't find anything about buildpacks and how to use them... Please do you have any resources I can visit for that?

Comment: Like if I have this `heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium.git`, where should I put it in? I know there is console in your_app -> More -> Run console, but it is completely different from what they show in guides...

Answer (score 0):

What about my question, I finally solved it. I just didn't see any tutorial for Java developer about Selenium on Heroku. Want to answer my question: we need to add to our project 2 buildpacks:
*https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/chromedriver.tgz*
*https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/google-chrome.tgz*
To add them you need to go to your application -> Settings -> Buildpacks -> Add buildpack and just paste links above 1 by 1.
[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk4jr.jpg)

So these drivers add 2 properties to our project which are paths to Google Chrome and Chromedriver. To start up your WebDriver you need this piece of code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067778/issue-while-executing-the-chromedriver-in-heroku-java-maven)

```
System.setProperty("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN", "/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome"); 
System.setProperty("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH", "/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome");   
options.addArguments("--enable-javascript"); 
options.addArguments("--headless"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); 
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://the-web_you_want");
```

That's it. Good luck!